Asymptotic Behavior of solution to Convection Diffusion equation
Suppose $u(x,t)$ is a solution to the convection diffusion equation $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+(\vec{v}\cdot\nabla)u=K\nabla^{2}u$ in a bounded domain $\Omega$. Assume that we have the boundary condition $\vec{v}\cdot\vec{n}=0$, and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}=0$ at the boundary (essentially no mass can flow out from $\Omega$). Is it always true that $u(x,t)$ approach a constant solution? I am not sure if there is any reference or textbook that discusses this. Any suggestion would be helpful.

Try solving the steady state equation ($\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=0$) and find out . . .

is $v$ constant?

It is not constant.
